# Telegram bot send photo by URL returns "Bad Request: wrong file identifier/HTTP URL specified"

Tags: telegram-bot

I am sending *photos by url* in my *Telegram bot*. For some photos, I am getting an error from Telegram:

```
{"ok":false,"error_code":400,"description":"Bad Request: wrong file identifier/HTTP URL specified"}
```

For example:
sending [this](https://drscdn.500px.org/photo/153590277/q%3D80_m%3D2000/v2?webp=true&sig=8b429a27872dfdb4f68ddc5edd488ce9e6a57977415fa323178cd62c5100a3ff) photo works:

```
https://api.telegram.org/bot<BOT_KEY>/sendPhoto?chat_id=<CHAT_ID>&photo=https%3A%2F%2Fdrscdn.500px.org%2Fphoto%2F153590277%2Fq%253D80_m%253D2000%2Fv2%3Fwebp%3Dtrue%26sig%3D8b429a27872dfdb4f68ddc5edd488ce9e6a57977415fa323178cd62c5100a3ff
```

but [this](https://drscdn.500px.org/photo/247611167/q%3D80_m%3D1500/v2?webp=true&sig=cfa117f225962250323c1202797abe8d45b47d59da12d780f4bf5231687c4331) file strangely doesn't work:

```
https://api.telegram.org/bot<BOT_KEY>/sendPhoto?chat_id=<CHAT_ID>&photo=https%3A%2F%2Fdrscdn.500px.org%2Fphoto%2F247611167%2Fq%253D80_m%253D1500%2Fv2%3Fwebp%3Dtrue%26sig%3Dcfa117f225962250323c1202797abe8d45b47d59da12d780f4bf5231687c4331
```

Notice that, for both examples:

- The URL is valid
- The MIME type seems OK (both are actually jpg files)
- File size is less than 10 MB

Am I doing something wrong? Or any idea about the problem?

Thanks,

Comment: Did you solve? how?

Comment: when using a url, the size of the photo cannot be more than 5MB. maybe that's the problem [documentation](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#inputfile)

Answer (score 14):

Possible solution:

Add useless attribute with random value to file url and retry until it successes.

I encountered this problem, too. I just found that nearly same files with nearly same urls have different behaviors. It shocked me. I don't think it's my files' fault, so I modified the file url by adding an useless attribute and tuning its value. After retrying many times, it worked!

You can have a try by running this snippet. The only differences are `&random=58` and `&random=64` at the end of each file url.

```html
<h5>Your Bot Token</h5>
<input id="token" type="text" style="width: 400px;" value="{YourBotToken}" />

<h3>200 OK Example</h3>
<form action="https://api.telegram.org/bot{YourBotToken}/sendPhoto" method="POST" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
  <textarea type="text/html" name="photo" rows="4" cols="70" readonly="readonly">http://api.map.baidu.com/staticimage?center=140.50,36.15&width=1024&height=576&zoom=6&amp;copyright=1&markers=140.50,36.15&markerStyles=l&random=58</textarea>
  <input type="text" name="chat_id" value="@{YourChatID}" />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="this.form.action='https://api.telegram.org/bot'+document.getElementById('token').value+'/sendPhoto';" />
</form>
<br><br>
<h3>400 Bad Request Example</h3>
<form action="https://api.telegram.org/bot{YourBotToken}/sendPhoto" method="POST" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
  <textarea type="text/html" name="photo" rows="4" cols="70" readonly="readonly">http://api.map.baidu.com/staticimage?center=140.50,36.15&width=1024&height=576&zoom=6&amp;copyright=1&markers=140.50,36.15&markerStyles=l&random=64</textarea>
  <input type="text" name="chat_id" value="@{YourChatID}" />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="this.form.action='https://api.telegram.org/bot'+document.getElementById('token').value+'/sendPhoto';" />
</form>
```

Comment: this solved my problem too. but have you found the actual problem? it is weird!

Comment: @kiasaty I think the problem is in Telegram server end. Maybe something wrong interrupted the download process. And now, to avoid endless waiting, I prefer to download and send my files on my local machine.

Comment: OMG you actually save my day! I do a LOT of research and Can't find why until putting some random atributtes on url. As a matter of fact I came with the same theory before (adding some random atributte to url) but never do it because I believe thats very stupid haha.

Comment: @JuanFernandoz lol happy to hear that~ stupid but worked

Comment: I like this solution after wasting 2 hours of my time :)

Comment: months ago, I got it fixed with random=777, \n
today I move the project to another VPS, got to add lala=66.
my url looks like this https://domain/filename.jpg?random=777&lala=66

Answer (score -1):

I've encountered the same problem recently.

API documentation [page](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sending-files) says:

> **Sending by URL**
>   ...
>   Other configurations may work but *we can't guarantee that they will*.

This means that if you want to be 100% sure, you should send your photos using `file_id` or `multipart/form-data`.

Comment: What does `multipart/form-data` mean? What fields? What encodings? I try to send the fields of the JSON message object as separate fields and encode the `reply_markup` field as JSON, sending the image data as `photo`, but I still just get 400 Bad Request. No indication of what is wrong.